# magento 2 UI Component form Character Limit Validation

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, form-validation

How to create custom Validation for UI Component Form? I want to create Validation for maximum character, not for max-word which is already available in Magento 2.
if any body knows please share the procedure.Thanks

Comment: Can you please share your code where you want to add?

Comment: @RohanHapani 

<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="validate-length" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
      Here i want to limit my character. i want that form sould only accept 250 character .

                    </item>

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to do like this :

```
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
<item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
<item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">250</item>
</item>
```

clean cache and check it.

Comment: thank you, its working. do you know how i can create my own validation?

Comment: Happy Coding !! :) You can accept this answer for helpful to other developer.

Comment: Yes. You can create custom validation by js. You can take reference from here. https://inchoo.net/magento-2/build-your-custom-form-validation-rule/

Comment: Now, You can Re-accept answer if this answer is useful in this above question ;)

Comment: let me try this.. after that i will accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: Okay. Feel free to ask me if any query will generate :)

Comment: well i have seen above website before , i think this validation is for jquery. As i want to create custom magento validation which can be use for UI Component and System.xml as well. Better if you demonstrate this with your own example cause i am new in magento. Thanks

Comment: Yes. I can give answer. But, you can create new question for that. Because, what's your question that I already gave answer and it's 100% working as you said. So, you can accept it. It's better if you create new question. So, for other user it's easy to get answer of this question :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81073/discussion-between-ali-ejaz-and-rohan-hapani).